# How to manage error text bigger than TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form that have one TextFormField called amount and when it validates on submit it displays error message, but I noticed that the length of the text is bigger than the field size and it does this

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icfR6.png)

I've put errorMaxLines: 5. If I put 1 line, it would show only "This is the error ..."

Is there a way to display the complete error message in one line, even if it is bigger than the field?

Something like this

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfKCR.png)

Code:

```
Widget textAmmount() {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 100, // i dont want it bigger
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: "Ammount",
        labelText: "Ammount",
      ),
      validator: (value) {           
        if (num.tryParse(value) == null) {
          return 'This is the error i want to display.';
        } 

        return null;
      },
    ),
  ),
);}
```

Comment: Where's the code to what you've tried

Comment: I edited adding the code. 
Just to clarify the validation works well just want the error not to fit the size of the field.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just use error style and error max line to define the maximum number of line to break to next line

```
...
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    errorStyle: TextStyle(),//<--Here
                    errorMaxLines: 1,//<-- Here
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: "Ammount",
                    labelText: "Ammount",
                  ),
...
```

Comment: thats exactly what i dont want.. i want just one line bigger than the field